# How to tell PowerShell to search the subfolder when it reaches the correct parent folder?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, I want to reach the \l3\n3 when my folder tree is like:

```
-l1
-l2
-l3-a1
   -b2
   -c3
```

after input `cd` with 3-times tabs, I got `cd .\l3\`. I just don't know which key to input to tell the shell that I need to check the sub folders in c3.

For now, I just input a `\`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Look up "recurse".

Comment: “recurse" is not the way I'm looking for. I'm looking for a key input to tell the shell to start list the next level folder when the "tab" key shows the correct upper lever folder name.

Comment: You mean like this? you tab, tab, tab then you're on l3, then you press the arrow-right key once, tab, tab, tab and then you're in c3?

Comment: -> is the what I'm looking for, although seems a little far on the keyboard. :) Thanks for comment..